# How do I set newTab.Content = XAMLElement? (WinUI 3)

Tags: c#, tabview, winui-3, app.xaml

I am currently working on a browser using WinUI 3. I have implemented TabView into my browser and whenever my c# code makes a new tab I want it to automatically use the TabContent(XAMLElement) Element from my Xaml file. But always shows an error that looks like this:

[image: error]

this is the code without the popup

```
private void TabView_AddTabButtonClick(TabView sender, object args)
{
     var newTab = new TabViewItem();
     newTab.IconSource = new SymbolIconSource() { Symbol = Symbol.Document };
     newTab.Header = "New Tab";

     // The Content of a TabViewItem is often a frame which hosts a page.
     newTab.Content = TabContent;
     sender.TabItems.Add(newTab);
}
```

XAML

```
<Window
    x:Class="VoidView.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:VoidView"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid x:Name="Browser" Margin="0,0,0,0"  Background="#222" >
        <TabView HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" AddTabButtonClick="TabView_AddTabButtonClick" TabCloseRequested="TabView_TabCloseRequested">
            <TabViewItem Height="35" x:Name="HomeTab" Header="Home" IsClosable="False">
                <TabViewItem.IconSource>
                    <SymbolIconSource Symbol="Home" />
                </TabViewItem.IconSource>

                <Grid x:Name="TabContent" Margin="0,0,0,0" Background="#282828">
                    <WebView2 x:Name="WebView" Source="https://google.com" Margin="0,52,0,0"/>
                    <Grid Margin="0,10,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="666">
                        <TextBox x:Name="AddressBar" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="576" PlaceholderText="Search or type a URL here..." TextAlignment="Center" />
                        <Button Height="32" Width="40" x:Name="Home" Click="Button_Click_1">
                            <FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe Fluent Icons" Glyph="&#xE80F;" Margin="-2,-1,-2,-1"/>
                        </Button>
                        <Button Height="32" Width="40" x:Name="Go" Margin="626,0,0,0" Click="Button_Click">
                            <FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe Fluent Icons" Glyph="&#xE751;" Margin="-2,-1,-2,-1"/>
                        </Button>
                    </Grid>
                    <Button x:Name="Refresh" Margin="0,10,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="32" Width="40" FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol" Click="Button_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                        <FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe Fluent Icons" Glyph="&#xe72c;" Margin="-2,-1,-2,-1"/>
                    </Button>
                    <Button x:Name="Backward" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="32" Width="40" FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol" Click="Backward_Click">
                        <FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe Fluent Icons" Glyph="&#xf0d3;" Margin="-2,-1,-2,-1"/>
                    </Button>
                    <Button x:Name="Forward" Margin="53,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="32" Width="40" FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol" Click="Forward_Click">
                        <FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe Fluent Icons" Glyph="&#xF0D2;" Margin="-2,-1,-2,-1"/>
                    </Button>
                </Grid>
            </TabViewItem>

            <TabView.TabStripHeader>
                <Grid x:Name="ShellTitlebarInset" Background="Transparent" />
            </TabView.TabStripHeader>
            <TabView.TabStripFooter>
                <Grid x:Name="CustomDragRegion" Background="Transparent" />
            </TabView.TabStripFooter>
        </TabView>


    </Grid>
</Window>
```

App looks like this:

[image: App]

> Thank you so much for taking your time and helping others!

Comment: You are not using a Frame as a tab content. If you take a look at WinUI3 gallery, they add a new Frame and then navigate to a single page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can not work, because the tab content is already added to a TabItem in XAML.

You could instead create a UserControl with all the content and add it to your tabpage:

```
newTab.Content = MyUserControl;
```

Or you could create a Frame and navigate to a page

```
Frame frame = new Frame();
frame.Navigate(typeof(TabPage));
newTab.Content = frame;
```

You can also check these links out:

https://github.com/microsoft/WinUI-Gallery/blob/winui2/WinUIGallery/ControlPages/TabViewPage.xaml.cs

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/controls/tab-view

**Edit:**

To create a new page:
Go to the Solutionexplorer in VS-Studio and rightclick on your project -> Add -> New Item -> Emty Page (WinUi3).

After you gave this page a name, you can throw all your xaml content, you want to put on your tabpage, into it.

Now in the typeof, you put the name of your page, which you have created before.

Comment: i do not understand the typeof(TabPage) part. what is TabPage??

Comment: i am not an experienced dev so pls excuse if im asking something dumb

Comment: In typeof(), you put the name of your XAML page, you can create by Clicking on the Solutionexplorer in VS-Studio and rightclick on your project -> Add -> New Item -> Emty Page (WinUi3)

Comment: shud i put the file name into typeof() class?

Comment: If the filename is similar to the class name. But you should use the class name of your Page. You find it in the NameOfYourPage.xaml.cs and then at the top class NameOfYourClass : Page.

Comment: nice! you cant believe how much i searched for this